# Android: is there a fixed size font? IE Force same height and width for uppercase and lowercase

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a custom android IME keyboard, and I'd like to have the uppercase and lowercase letters be the same height and width. Is there any way to acheive this?

IE :

```kotlin
Text(
  text = "A",
  fontSize = ? // This has uppercase characters much larger.
  fontFamily = FontFamily.MonoSpace // Even this still has much larger uppercase letters
)
```